# How do I place an image in a "tcolorbox" with overhang?

Tags: graphics, floats, align, tcolorbox, minipage

I am currently trying to position an image next to a formatted text inside a "tcolorbox".
My idea is that the image should protrude above and below this box.
I have already tried it with minipages but without the desired success. It looks like I can align it to a top line, but I can't move this line further up.

In the image I attached you can see above the red line approximately what is generated by my code. The black blob is an graphic. I added the thin yellow/white line for debugging so I can see better what is happening.
Below the red line you can see what I have in mind. The text and the image are centred in the band.

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree and the idea with the minipages isn't effective. If someone suggests an alternative which also leads to the desired result, I am open to it.

[image]

```
\newtcolorbox{bgbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,leftright skip=0pt,boxrule=0pt,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners,#1}


\vspace{2.5cm}
\begin{bgbox}[height=3cm,colback=background,width=\textwidth,size=minimal, size=minimal, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=0.5cm]
    \begin{minipage}[t][5cm][t]{0.55\textwidth}
        \begin{framed}
            \Huge{}\color{mydarkgreen}\textsc{My Name}\newline%
            \fontsize{12pt}{18pt}\selectfont
            \color{mylightblue}This is my Adress $\vert$ 0123 456789\\
            MoreAdress $\vert$ 12345 MyCity
        \end{framed}
    \end{minipage}%

    \hfill%     

    \begin{minipage}[t][5cm][t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{framed}
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{./images/profile.png}   
        \end{framed}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{bgbox}%
```

Here is where I got the idea with the "bgbox" thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466214/gap-in-rule-line-using-tcolorbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the figure using  `overlay`.

The distance between the right edge of the image and the right edge of the page is set to 3 cm (in this example), regardless of the width of the image.

[image: a]

Try this code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    

\newtcolorbox{bgbox}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    spread sidewards,
    frame hidden,
    left*=0pt, right*=0pt, boxrule=0pt, 
    colback=yellow!20,
    overlay={%
        \node[anchor=east] 
        at ([xshift=-3cm] frame.east){\includegraphics[width=6cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};},
    #1}
    
\begin{document}
    \definecolor{navy}{RGB}{10, 35 63}
    \definecolor{gold}{RGB}{201, 151, 44}
    \begin{bgbox}[height=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=0.5cm]%          
                \Huge\textcolor{red}{\textsc{My Name}}
                \newline%
                \fontsize{12pt}{18pt}\selectfont
                \textcolor{navy}{This is my Adress $\vert$ 0123 456789\\
                MoreAdress $\vert$ 12345 MyCity}
        \end{bgbox}%    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a MWE to work with, but is this what you want to get?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, height=3cm, colback=yellow, overlay={\node at ([xshift=-3cm]frame.east) {\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=4cm]{example-image-a}};}]
some text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]